# Why the angularjs one-way bind function run twice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a modal view:

```
<ion-content id="friendContent" class="scroll-content has-header has-subheader" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);">
    <ion-list class="list">
        <ion-item ng-repeat="objFriendInfo in objFriendInfoList | filter:{ Remark: data.searchQuery }" class="item item-avatar-left item-button-right searchFriendItemBackgroundColor"
            ng-click="FriendList('chat',objFriendInfo,$event)">
            <img class="imgFriendUser" ng-class="{ 'gray':objFriendInfo.state == 0 }" ng-src="{{::objFriendInfo.icon }}">
            <h2 class="light">{{::GetAndSaveFriendName('friendlist_UserName',objFriendInfo.Remark,'16px', objFriendInfo) }}</h2>
            <h3 class="positive" ng-click="FriendList('travellog',objFriendInfo,$event)">{{::GetAndSaveFriendTravellogName('friendlist_TravellogName',objFriendInfo.TravelLog_Name,'14px', objFriendInfo) }}</h3>
            <div class="buttons" style="top:15px !important;">
                <button class="center button button-small button-positive ion-edit" ng-if="objFriendInfo.id != user.id" style="font-size:16px;" ng-click="FriendList('remark',objFriendInfo,$event)"></button>
                <button class="center button button-small button-positive icon-mapsay_delete" ng-if="objFriendInfo.id != user.id" style="font-size:25px;" ng-click="FriendList('delete',objFriendInfo,$event)"></button>
            </div>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

and the function GetAndSaveFriendName code is:

```
$scope.GetAndSaveFriendName = function (name, text, fontSize, objFriendInfor) {
                var strDisplayName = "";

                console.log(text);

                if (objFriendInfor.strDisplayName) {
                    strDisplayName = objFriendInfor.strDisplayName;    
                } else {
                    strDisplayName = ServiceForChatCommon.GetShowDivText(name, text, fontSize);
                    objFriendInfor.strDisplayName = strDisplayName;
                }

                return strDisplayName;
            };
```

The problem is the function GetAndSaveFriendName will run twice, what's the reason?

**[EDIT]**

I decalre the controller like:

```
.config([
        '$stateProvider',
        function ($stateProvider) {
            $stateProvider
                .state('tabs.chat', {
                    url: '/chat',
                    views: {
                        'chatView': {
                            templateUrl: 'components/chat-component/chat-view.html',
                            controller: 'chatController'
                        }
                    }
                })
        }]);
```

Comment: usually this problem happens cause you decalre twice the controller .. for example one in your html (data-ng-controller="YOURCONTROLLER" )and one in your routing ... is it possibile?

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi Sir, I only decalre once in my router file.

Comment: which kind a router are you using? .. ui-router? .. be sure how you declare your routing (with / final)

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi Sir, please see the "EDIT".

Comment: mmm sorry now i take  a better loook to your html ... you're calling the function in a foor loop .. so this is why it's called...one way data binding doesn't mean it is called once only ...

Comment: how many items do you have in your loops? ..two?

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi It's uncertain, may be 20 or more.

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi And if there is three items, the console log shows:   "one item" "two item" "three item" "one item" "two item" "three item"

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi Hi, sir. I think I found the reason: The $digest of AngularJs run at least twice, the second recyle make sure the DOM is the up-to-date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the reason. The $digest of AngularJs run at least twice, the second recyle make sure the DOM is the up-to-date.